# client - server position syncronization in flash

Tags: flash, networking, server, client

I trying implement client - server position syncronization. Every 20 game ticks i sending to flash client correction of player position... and it always wrong on client, flash always cant predict player position. I think it due to different frame rate or different time on server and client (server is running on 30 fps when client on 60 fps).

Take a look [here](http://www.realmofthemadgod.com/). How can I implement so precise player movements like they did? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This document](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Source_Multiplayer_Networking) explains what you need to know.